# Need org.eclipse.jface for Eclipse Plug-in (Eclipse Profiler)

Tags: eclipse, download, profiler, jface

Good afternoon--

After reading a lot of posts on this site about a good profile tool, and in my search for something that will produce a Call Graph, I have found the Eclipse Profiler will meet my needs nicely.

However, when I try to run the program (create a new profile), I get an error regarding org.eclipse.jface, which I *believe* is erroring out because I do not have that package (or at least, I cannot find it on my computer).  I searched for several hours last night, and see lots of references to USING jface, but have been able to find no location from which to get it.

Here is the error: 
**Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".**

I am not including the entire stack trace, as I am not sure it would do any good.  Here is my environment info as provided by Eclipse:

- eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
- java.version=1.6.0_18
- java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
- BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
- Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product
- Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product

Any insight is appreciated.
Kristin

Comment: The top part of your stack trace is important.  JFace is a framework bundle, and if it catches a thrown exception it will report that error.  But the stack trace will tell you what caused that error, and it's probably not JFace.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in org.eclipse.jface is used inside Eclipse for displaying graphical interfaces (e.g. lists or tree widgets or wizards), so it should be available when using the Eclipse Profiler. However, the exception you provided could simply happen because some code is written incorrectly and during method invocation from another plug-in simply an exception is thrown - however, I cannot verify this without the stack trace.

However, everything I have written before is based on the idea that the error is thrown in the Eclipse development environment and not by the executed program, that is instrumented by the Eclipse Profiler (this instrumentation is needed, as the tool calculates dynamic call graphs: it remembers which methods are called or not).

If the exception is thrown by your (instrumented) program, then I don't understand why does the instrumented code depend on JFace. I believe, you are not developing an Eclipse plug-in, because then in most case the JFace plug-ins are available - in case of standalone Java application this would be more of an error, and I'd suggest using a different call graph tool.

If the call graphs are needed only during development, I suggest using JDT's built-in call graph tool (available when right clicking a method in the Java editor and selecting Open Call Hierarchy - or the default short-cut is Ctrl+Alt+H).

Comment: I have not been yet able to instrument my code, I have only tried to generate a new profile (first step after installation of Eclipse Profiler)...so I *believe* that it is not a problem with my code. I do understand that this assumption could be wrong, but I am novice enough to hope that it is not.  <grin>  You are correct that I am not developing a plug-in.  I only need to generate the call graph during development, and so it sounds like the JDT would be the way to go.  I am currently checking to see how to get the JDT (don't have it already that I know of).  The options aren't available.

Comment: I am guessing, but it appears that I have the choice or not to include that in the Eclipse version that I downloaded. I have downloaded Eclipse Helios SR2, and will be checking it out shortly.  Wish me luck.....

Comment: Ok, I found out that I need to get the Type Hierarchy, and THEN I can get the Call Hierarchy. It doesn't really show me what I need, no matter what view I look at. I also found out that I *did* have this capability in my previous eclipse version.  I plan to see if I can get the Eclipse Project downloaded and working successfully in a pristine copy of Eclipse with no additional plugins.

Comment: I don't think, the failure lies in your code but in the Eclipse Profiler; however, as I don't know that very much I cannot tell you how to fix it. However, if you could tell me what do you like to see in the call graph maybe I could recommend some other solution.

Comment: Zoltan, thanks very much for getting back to me.  The call graph was to be able to see the reliances on various methods. The Eclipse Profiler used color to indicate how often various methods were used, and we *really* liked this...but the real goal was to be able to do some required calculations.  We ended up using another tool that gave us the basics, but not the cool color graph. It worked out OK in the end.  Thank you for your kind offer!

Comment: I see - that feature could be really useful. Glad to help.